# Closing jQuery Tools tooltip on iphone/ipad with touchstart

Tags: jquery, ipad, tooltip, touchstart

I have the following code being run if an iphone/ipad/ipod is detected:

```
$('.tooltip-trigger').tooltip({offset: [20, -110],relative:true, events: { def: 'touchstart,blur'} });
```

I have got the initial touch working instead of on hover by declaring def:'touchstart', however the boxes do not close and calling another touchstart like def: 'touchstart,touchstart' does not work. Neither does def: 'toggle' which seems logical to me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by placing a close button on the tooltip for smartphones and tablets only

Answer (score 3):

I did the same thing. Here's how:

```
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
```

My tooltip function looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).tooltip({
        items: "[data-fn]",
          content: function() {
              var element = $( this );
              if ( element.is( "[data-fn]" ) ) {
              var s = element.attr('data-fn');
              var fn = /* some text content */

              if (isiPad) fn += "<div align=right'><a href='#' class='ipadTooltipHack'>close</a></div>";
              return fn;
              } 
          }     
       });
});
```

Finally I added this:

```
$('.ipadTooltipHack').tooltip('close');
```

Seems to work.

I tried adding a hide: option to the tooltip function to autohide after 10s which worked but then you could not open that tooltip again until a different one was open.

Answer (score 1):

I could not replicate the solution by Bill Nobes and nlsbshtr, pressing the 'close' link also navigated to the top of the page. I changed it the a slightly easier solution.

This is based on jQuery and the Modernizr.touch function to detect if we are on a touch device. It uses the standard **title** tag and it closes the opened tooltip using the recommended close-method on click.

```
$(function() {
    $( '.tooltip-trigger' ).tooltip(
    {
        content: function() {
            var element = $( this );
            var s = element.attr('title');
            if ('' == s)
                return null;
            if (Modernizr.touch) // using Modernizr to detect touch devices.
                s += "&lt;div align=right'>&lt;a href=\"javascript:$('.tooltip-trigger').tooltip('close');\" class='touchTooltipHack'>close&lt;/a>&lt;/div>";
            return s;
        } 
    });
});
```

replace  `.tooltip-trigger` with the class of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

user2956826 answer follows the jqueryui recommendation [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8850) - which is:-

> Safari Mobile 7.0+ (and likely earlier versions too) suffers from a bug where click events aren't fired on elements that aren't typically interactive

...detailed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile)

However, the HTML special characters included seemed to be displayed literally in the browser and I needed to replace them with non-html equivalents within the double quotes. There is also (trivially) a missing single-quote in the same line around align=right so I have for eg.

```
 s += "<div align='right'><a href=\"javascript:$('.tooltip-trigger').tooltip('close');\" class='touchTooltipHack'>close</a></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works:

Add css:

`.ui-tooltip{cursor:pointer;}`

Add jquery:

```
$('body').on('click','.ui-tooltip', function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

After that, tooltips will close, when you click on it, even on iPads.

Answer (score 0):

well, just ran in the same issue, but had one more requirement - since I have multiple tooltips I need at least to close opened tooltips while a new one is opened. Came with this easy implementation, maybe will help somebody out

```
var $tooltipCaller = $('.tooltip');

  $tooltipCaller.tooltip({
    open: function (e, ui) {
      $tooltipCaller.not(this).tooltip('close');
    }
  });
```