# jQuery tooltip mouseout fix on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, tooltip

I use jQuery tooltip, it works fine but not on iPad, the tooltip is displayed when I click the link, then I cannot get rid of it!!

I included this plugin

`<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>`

which works fine with drag for example, but doesn't handle the mouseout for the tooltip, how can I fix this?

Comment: this is expected behavior since ipad does not support mouseout!

Comment: yes, but using this plugin should handle the mapping of events to ipad touch

Comment: mouseover and mouseout on ipad?

Answer (score 1):

Various suggestions can be found in the answers here: [Closing jQuery Tools tooltip on iphone/ipad with touchstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977400/closing-jquery-tools-tooltip-on-iphone-ipad-with-touchstart?rq=1)

I ended up switching to the Bootstrap tooltip and using the following:

```
                $('#myButton').tooltip().click(function(e) {
                    $(this).tooltip('toggle');
                });
```

Something similar might work fine for jQuery depending on your requirements.