# jQuery UI tooltip not hiding in iOS device

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have developed a web project using HTML + jQuery and now i am facing some issues in my application accessing from iOS device.

In my project i have used tooltip for textbox controls . Tooltip works fine in desktop browsers (Chrome , Firefox , IE ) , but when it comes to Mobile device (touch device) mainly iOS device tooltip is not hiding. It Stucks on page blocking other controls.

Tooltip Code : JS

```
$(document).tooltip({
    position: {
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
        using: function(position, feedback) {
            $(this).css(position);
            $("<div>")
                .addClass("arrows")
                .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                .appendTo(this);
        }
    }
});
```

I have searched a lot in web and i can see in some posts saying jQuery tooltip had some dependency in iOS device.

Please suggest me a good solution to solve this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing jQuery Tools tooltip on iphone/ipad with touchstart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977400/closing-jquery-tools-tooltip-on-iphone-ipad-with-touchstart)